# ld: framework not found AFNetworking, clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using **CocoaPods** in my application, the vision of Xcode is 8.2.

I get the following error :

[image]

Any suggestion is good

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following methods but i'm not sure whether these will fix your problems or not.

- clean your project ( Product -> Clean )
- delete derived data ( Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data )
- build your project ( cmd + B )

if above method doesn't solve your problem, try reinstalling the AFNetworking again.

Comment: I did as what you said, but it not works, the error is still appear.